# iPhone Camera Overlay issue

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, overlay

I am using Custom Overlay for camera in my iPhone app,I have followed [this](http://www.devsrealm.com/objective-c/custom-camera-app-1/) tutorial.
My problem is-the overlay comes before the shutter opens,means on the shutter users can see the overlay items(buttons,image etc)

I have tried with a timer,to delay the overlay appearance for the time of shutter opening animation,but that is not a right way.

Any better idea?

```
-(void)onShowCam
{
   NSLog(@"sdadas");

    overlay = [[CustomOverlayView alloc]
           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH)];

    overlay.delegate = self;

   .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
    cameraOverlay=[[ImagePickerController alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH)];
         imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
         imagePicker.delegate=self;
         imagePicker.showsCameraControls=NO;
         imagePicker.cameraFlashMode=UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
         [imagePicker setCameraOverlayView:cameraOverlay];

//Show camera
         [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

On the iPad this problem doesn't exist, and the overlay view is behind the shutter animation by default. But on the iPhone, the overlay appears at front.

I've found a solution that worked for me.

You have to set your overlay view as a subview in this method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (!viewController)
        return;

    UIView* controllerViewHolder = viewController.view;
    UIView* controllerCameraView = [[controllerViewHolder subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIView* controllerPreview = [[controllerCameraView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    [controllerCameraView insertSubview:self.overlayView aboveSubview:controllerPreview];
}
```

Hope it helps

Original source: 
http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/06/18/uiimagepickercontroller-in-3-0/